# Embed youtube video with dark player?

Tags: html, flash, youtube, embedded-flashplayer

When watching a video on youtube you get a dark player
[image: Dark youtube player controls]

But when you embed you get the standard light player
[image: Light youtube player]

So,
How can I change the embedded video to use the dark controls?

I know that I can view the source and copy the object for the video... but there has to be a more "official" way of doing this.

Comment: embedded tag is not for HTML embeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by modifying the embed code.

> Simply add a "theme" parameter to the iframe source with a value of "dark".

From here:

- http://claudiuceia.info/article/embed-new-dark-youtube-player/